# ScheduledExecutorService redundancy in multi-instance environment

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduler, scheduledexecutorservice

I am running a java web app on multiple instances behind a load balancer.

When a user triggers a certain Servlet, a `ScheduledExecutorService` schedules a task for some time in the future. Obviously, this task is only set on the instance which the user was on.

In order to achieve redundancy, what is the best way to ensure that the task is added to the other instances as well? That is, if something should happen to the instance where the task was scheduled, I want to ensure that the other instances have the task scheduled so that they can carry it out.

(I am not worried about the task being executed multiple times, I can just mark it as executed in my database, which is shared among all instances).

One solution is to just have a task scheduled for every hour on both servers which checks (via the db) if to carry out said task. While this is doable, it requires querying the database every hour or minute. So, if there is a way to do it by scheduling a task once, that would be better.